# axios post request to send form data

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, axios, ajaxform, axios-cookiejar-support

axios `POST` request is hitting the url on the controller but setting null values to my POJO class, when I go through developer tools in chrome, the payload contains data. What am I doing wrong?

**Axios POST Request:**

```
var body = {
    userName: 'Fred',
    userEmail: 'Flintstone@gmail.com'
}

axios({
    method: 'post',
    url: '/addUser',
    data: body
})
.then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
})
.catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
});
```

**Browser Response:**

[image]

If I set headers as:

```
headers:{
  Content-Type:'multipart/form-data'
}
```

The request throws the error

> Error in posting multipart/form-data. Content-Type header is missing boundary

If I make the same request in postman it's working fine and sets values to my POJO class.

Can anyone explain how to set boundary or how can I send form data using axios.

Comment: What does this have to do with react and redux? Can we just make it generic JS?

Answer (score 694, accepted):

You can post axios data by using [FormData()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) like:

```js
var bodyFormData = new FormData();
```

And then add the fields to the form you want to send:

```js
bodyFormData.append('userName', 'Fred');
```

If you are uploading images, you may want to use `.append`

```js
bodyFormData.append('image', imageFile);
```

And then you can use axios post method (You can amend it accordingly)

```js
axios({
  method: "post",
  url: "myurl",
  data: bodyFormData,
  headers: { "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data" },
})
  .then(function (response) {
    //handle success
    console.log(response);
  })
  .catch(function (response) {
    //handle error
    console.log(response);
  });
```

Related GitHub issue:

[Can't get a .post with 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' to work @ axios/axios](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/318)

Comment: bodyFormData.set is not a function  i got this error

Comment: You need to use append instead of set.

Comment: bodyFormData.append is worked for me too. not sure why `set` not working

Comment: Why did we have to use `append` instead of `set` for uploading images?

Comment: Your config object is wrong. It should be:
`{
    method: 'post',
    url: 'myurl',
    data: bodyFormData,
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' }
  }`

Comment: @Aaqib I am trying the same thing but i am getting error. Can you please explain how did you create "imageFile". I guess i am doing this wrong.

Comment: may I ask you to have a look at an `axios` related question here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59470085/vue-js-validation-fails-for-file-upload-in-axios-when-multipart-form-data-used ?

Comment: in nodejs you'll need `npm install --save form-data`

Comment: Latest axios sets the `Content-Type` header automatically with boundary, so better not mess with it.

Comment: Btw just a quick side note for a thing that took my half an hour: FormData can only handle String and blob values. Therefor it will convert booleans and null values (and also integers) to strings with 'true'/'false' / 'null' / eg. '1337'. You backend may fail when it for example is expecting an integer or null for a field and is handed over a string.

Comment: In `nodejs` you can use `URLSearchParams` instead. For example: `const formData = new URLSearchParams({
  param1: 'this',
  param2: 'is',
  param3: 'neat',
}) `

Comment: install form-data please

Comment: In my particular case, I needed to add the content-length header too               `'Content-Length': formData.getLengthSync(),`

Answer (score 96):

In my case I had to add the **boundary** to the **header** like the following:

```js
const form = new FormData();
form.append(item.name, fs.createReadStream(pathToFile));

const response = await axios({
    method: 'post',
    url: 'http://www.yourserver.com/upload',
    data: form,
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': `multipart/form-data; boundary=${form._boundary}`,
    },
});
```

This solution is also useful if you're working with React Native.

Comment: This solved my issue when trying to post to imgur's api. Not mentioned anywhere on the docs, but without it you get a 400 Invalid URL response.

Comment: `FormData._boundary` is undefined in both Chrome 76 and Firefox 67, and [axios deletes the Content-Type header anyway](https://github.com/axios/axios/blob/503418718f669fcc674719fd862b355605d7b41f/lib/adapters/xhr.js#L15-L17), so this should have no effect.

Comment: The boundary part was the only thing that was missing from my code, worked perfeclty in node!

Comment: Hi, one problem though this works only in android did you managed to make it work on iOS devices?

Comment: @KevinRED  Yes, at the time I was actually using React Native with an iOS app...

Comment: this will miss import header field like Content-Length, which will get  400 error from some backend  service

Comment: fs.createReadStream can only be used on server side not frontend.

Comment: what is `_boundary`? i got undefined!

Comment: `_boundary` only exists on `form-data` npm module, not on the native FormData in the Browser! And you should use `getBoundary()` instead, or better `getHeaders()`. In the Browser you need only to set ` 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'` without the boundary thing.

Comment: Thank you!! This is necessary for Box API.

Comment: @LuizDias i am also using react-native. It was working fine before even without boundary, but after i upgraded axios and form-data it is complaining that boundary is missing. None of the solutions is working, formdata._boundary as well as formdata.getHeaders() is giving undefined.

Answer (score 53):

Check out [querystring](https://www.npmjs.com/package/querystring).

You can use it as follows:

```
var querystring = require('querystring');
axios.post('http://something.com/', querystring.stringify({ foo: 'bar' }));
```

Comment: This is even better in a node environment

Comment: If you have nested objects in your data, 'querystring' may not work as expected. In that case, you can use 'qs' module to stringify the data.

Comment: This is not form data. This is a url-encoded form format.

Comment: The querystring package has been deprecated for some reason

Comment: Querystring is deprecated. This is the current method:    const data = new URLSearchParams(dataObject).toString(); Then post that data object.

Answer (score 37):

## Upload (multiple) binary files

### Node.js

Things become complicated when you want to post files via `multipart/form-data`, especially multiple binary files. Below is a working example:

```
const FormData = require('form-data')
const fs = require('fs')
const path = require('path')

const formData = new FormData()
formData.append('files[]', JSON.stringify({ to: [{ phoneNumber: process.env.RINGCENTRAL_RECEIVER }] }), 'test.json')
formData.append('files[]', fs.createReadStream(path.join(__dirname, 'test.png')), 'test.png')
await rc.post('/restapi/v1.0/account/~/extension/~/fax', formData, {
  headers: formData.getHeaders()
})
```

- Instead of `headers: {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' }` I prefer `headers: formData.getHeaders()`
- I use `async` and `await` above, you can change them to plain Promise statements if you don't like them
- In order to add your own headers, you just `headers: { ...yourHeaders, ...formData.getHeaders() }`

---

**Newly added content below:**

### Browser

Browser's `FormData` is different from the NPM package 'form-data'. The following code works for me in browser:

**HTML:**

```
<input type="file" id="image" accept="image/png"/>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
const formData = new FormData()

// add a non-binary file
formData.append('files[]', new Blob(['{"hello": "world"}'], { type: 'application/json' }), 'request.json')

// add a binary file
const element = document.getElementById('image')
const file = element.files[0]
formData.append('files[]', file, file.name)
await rc.post('/restapi/v1.0/account/~/extension/~/fax', formData)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this example, had a hard time figuring out why multiple file upload was not working.

Comment: I'm not an expert, but in my case I have managed to avoid these complications (`concat-stream`, `async` and `await`) for multiple file upload by using `for(var x = 0; x<this.state.files.length; x++) { formData.append('files[]', this.state.files[x]) }` so I can submit using `axios.post(url, formData, config)`

Comment: @laimison thanks, it works for me. I've updated my answer.

Comment: @TylerLong I can't find any getHeaders method in FormData API. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData

Comment: headers: formData.getHeaders() is what got it working for me. Thanks.

Comment: formData.getHeaders() works but what about token we need to add???

Comment: @GvsAkhil check my latest update about how to add your own headers.

Comment: This is not working with mutler on node.js side when u have binary file

Comment: @ИгорТашевски Please report the issue to the multer project.

Answer (score 18):

**Using application/x-www-form-urlencoded format in axios**

> By default, axios serializes JavaScript objects to JSON. To send data
> in the application/x-www-form-urlencoded format instead, you can use
> one of the following options.

**Browser**

In a browser, you can use the URLSearchParams API as follows:

```
const params = new URLSearchParams();

params.append('param1', 'value1');

params.append('param2', 'value2');

axios.post('/foo', params);
```

Note that `URLSearchParams` is not supported by all browsers (see caniuse.com), but there is a polyfill available (make sure to polyfill the global environment).

**Alternatively, you can encode data using the qs library:**

```
const qs = require('qs');

axios.post('/foo', qs.stringify({ 'bar': 123 }));
```

**Or in another way (ES6),**

```
import qs from 'qs';

const data = { 'bar': 123 };

const options = {

  method: 'POST',

  headers: { 'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },

  data: qs.stringify(data),

  url, };

axios(options);
```

Answer (score 18):

**2020 ES6 way of doing**

Having the form in html I binded in data like so:

DATA:

```
form: {
   name: 'Joan Cap de porc',
   email: 'fake@email.com',
   phone: 2323,
   query: 'cap d\ou'
   file: null,
   legal: false
},
```

onSubmit:

```
async submitForm() {
  const formData = new FormData()
  Object.keys(this.form).forEach((key) => {
    formData.append(key, this.form[key])
  })

  try {
    await this.$axios.post('/ajax/contact/contact-us', formData)
    this.$emit('formSent')
  } catch (err) {
    this.errors.push('form_error')
  }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

## **The 2022 way**

The Axios documentation hasn't updated yet, but there is a convenient way to to make formdata nowadays, by using the `axios.toFormData()` method.

Here is its TypeScript definition:

```js
export function toFormData(sourceObj: object, targetFormData?: GenericFormData, options?: FormSerializerOptions): GenericFormData;
```

**Example:**

```js
const formData = axios.toFormData({"myField":"myValue"})

const response = await axios({
  method: "post",
  url: "...",
  data: formData,
  headers: { ... }
})
```

**Source:**

You can find the following in Axios's Change log

[1.0.0] - 2022-10-04

Added generic TS types for the exposed toFormData helper [#4668](https://github.com/axios/axios/pull/4668)

Added enhanced toFormData implementation with additional options [4704](https://github.com/axios/axios/pull/4704)

Comment: Note that boolean and numbers must be encoded as string.
For example, `axios.toFormData({"foo": true})` will throw `TypeError: data should be a string, Buffer or Uint8Array`. Do  `axios.toFormData({"foo": "true}")` instead.

Answer (score 6):

Even More straightforward:

```
axios.post('/addUser',{
    userName: 'Fred',
    userEmail: 'Flintstone@gmail.com'
})
.then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
})
.catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
});
```

Comment: Yes, as it seems, if there are no file uploads, this is the easiest way.

Answer (score 6):

```
import axios from "axios";
import qs from "qs";   

const url = "https://yourapplicationbaseurl/api/user/authenticate";
    let data = {
      Email: "testuser@gmail.com",
      Password: "Admin@123"
    };
    let options = {
      method: "POST",
      headers: { "content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" },
      data: qs.stringify(data),
      url
    };
    axios(options)
      .then(res => {
        console.log("yeh we have", res.data);
      })
      .catch(er => {
        console.log("no data sorry ", er);
      });
  };
```

Answer (score 6):

I had the similar issues when using **FormData** with axios to make calls on https://apps.dev.microsoft.com service and it error-red out with "**The request body must contain the following parameter: 'grant_type'**"

After reformatting the data from

```
{
  grant_type: 'client_credentials',
  id: '123',
  secret: '456789'
}
```

to

```
"grant_type=client_credentials&id=123&secret=456789"
```

and the following code worked:

```
const config: AxiosRequestConfig = {
    method: 'post',
    url: https://apps.dev.microsoft.com/auth,
    data: 'grant_type=client_credentials&id=123&secret=456789',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    }
};

axios(config)
.then(function (response) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data));
})
.catch(function (error) {
  console.log(error);
});
```

Comment: You saved me! For some reason building the object with `FormData` didn't work but when I did something like    `data: 'grant_type=client_credentials&id=123&secret=456789',` as you suggested it did the trick!

Comment: I have to say that indeed this worked! Postman worked with formdata but it didn't on my project. +1

Answer (score 5):

A **[*boundary*](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc1341/7_2_Multipart.html)** *(which is used, by the server, to parse the payload)* is set when the request is sent. You can't obtain the boundary before making the request. So, a better way to get this is using `getBoundary()` from your [FormData](https://github.com/form-data/form-data).

```js
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('userName', 'Fred');
formData.append('file0', fileZero);
formData.append('file1', fileOne);

axios({
  method: "post",
  url: "myurl",
  data: formData,
  headers: {
      'Content-Type':  `multipart/form-data; ${formData.getBoundary()}`,
})
  .then(function (response) {
    //handle success
    console.log(response);
  })
  .catch(function (response) {
    //handle error
    console.log(response);
  });
```

Comment: It worked for me with just `'Content-Type':  'multipart/form-data'`

Answer (score 3):

i needed to calculate the content length aswell

```
const formHeaders = form.getHeaders();
formHeaders["Content-Length"] = form.getLengthSync()

const config = {headers: formHeaders}

return axios.post(url, form, config)
.then(res => {
    console.log(`form uploaded`)
})
```

Comment: WIthout this I couldn't get the response. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I needed to upload many files at once using **axios** and I struggled for a while because of the **FormData** API:

```js
// const instance = axios.create(config);

let fd = new FormData();
for (const img of images) { // images is an array of File Object
  fd.append('images', img, img.name); // multiple upload
}

const response = await instance({
  method: 'post',
  url: '/upload/',
  data: fd
})
```

**I did NOT** specify the `content-type: multipart/form-data` header!

Answer (score 1):

On newest axios version you can send a post form data by using:

```
axios.postForm(url, data);
```

It will have the same result as creating one by one in form instance:

```
var bodyFormData = new FormData();
bodyFormData.append("abc", "xyz");
```

You can view more about it in axios Docs: https://axios-http.com/docs/multipart

Answer (score 0):

The above method worked for me but since it was something I needed often, I used a basic method for flat object. Note, I was also using Vue and not REACT

```
packageData: (data) => {
  const form = new FormData()
  for ( const key in data ) {
    form.append(key, data[key]);
  }
  return form
}
```

Which worked for me until I ran into more complex data structures with nested objects and files which then let to the following

```
packageData: (obj, form, namespace) => {
  for(const property in obj) {
    // if form is passed in through recursion assign otherwise create new
    const formData = form || new FormData()
    let formKey

    if(obj.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
      if(namespace) {
        formKey = namespace + '[' + property + ']';
      } else {
        formKey = property;
      }

      // if the property is an object, but not a File, use recursion.
      if(typeof obj[property] === 'object' && !(obj[property] instanceof File)) {
        packageData(obj[property], formData, property);
      } else {
        // if it's a string or a File
      formData.append(formKey, obj[property]);
      }
    }
  }
  return formData;
}
```

Comment: objectToFormData is undefined and formData is returned outside the for, but is defined inside the for.  formData is easy, but what is objectToFormData  supposed to be?

Comment: I think its supposed to be the name of the function. because it's meant to be recursive, so i assume you can change the `objectToFormData` to `packageData` or vice versa

Answer (score 0):

For me it worked using axios, typescript and form-data(v4.0.0):

```
import FormData from "form-data";
import axios from "axios";

async function login() {
  var data = new FormData();
  data.append("User", "asdf");
  const return = await axios.post(
    "https://ptsv2.com/t/1q9gx-1652805776/post", data,
    { headers: data.getHeaders() }
  );
  console.log(return);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work well when needing to POST x-www-form-urlencoded data using axios from a NodeJS environment. You may need to add an Authorization header to the config.headers object if the endpoint requires authentication.

```
const config = {
  headers: {
    accept: 'application/json',
    'cache-control': 'no-cache',
    'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
  }

const params = new URLSearchParams({key1: value1, key2: value2});

return axios
  .post(url, params.toString(), config)
  .then((response) => {
    return response.data;
  })
  .catch((error) => console.error(error));
```

Answer (score 0):

Axios has it built in.

```
axios.postForm('https://localhost', {
  my_field: 'my value',
});
```

Answer (score -1):

In my case, the problem was that the format of the FormData append operation needed the additional "options" parameter filling in to define the filename thus:

```
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append(fieldName, fileBuffer, {filename: originalName});
```

I'm seeing a lot of complaints that axios is broken, but in fact the root cause is not using form-data properly. My versions are:

```
"axios": "^0.21.1",
"form-data": "^3.0.0",
```

On the receiving end I am processing this with multer, and the original problem was that the file array was not being filled - I was always getting back a request with no files parsed from the stream.

In addition, it was necessary to pass the form-data header set in the axios request:

```
        const response = await axios.post(getBackendURL() + '/api/Documents/' + userId + '/createDocument', formData, {
        headers: formData.getHeaders()
    });
```

My entire function looks like this:

```
async function uploadDocumentTransaction(userId, fileBuffer, fieldName, originalName) {
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append(fieldName, fileBuffer, {filename: originalName});

    try {
        const response = await axios.post(
            getBackendURL() + '/api/Documents/' + userId + '/createDocument',
            formData,
            {
                headers: formData.getHeaders()
            }
        );

        return response;
    } catch (err) {
        // error handling
    }
}
```

The value of the "fieldName" is not significant, unless you have some receiving end processing that needs it.

Comment: And what about browser formData object? Axios not working well with browser form-data

Answer (score -2):

https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios

**Its Working**

// "content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
// commit this

```
import axios from 'axios';

let requestData = {
      username : "abc@gmail.cm",
      password: "123456"
    };
   
    const url = "Your Url Paste Here";

    let options = {
      method: "POST",
      headers: { 
        'Content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',

        Authorization: 'Bearer ' + "your token Paste Here",
      },
      data: JSON.stringify(requestData),
      url
    };
    axios(options)
      .then(response => {
        console.log("K_____ res :- ", response);
        console.log("K_____ res status:- ", response.status);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log("K_____ error :- ", error);
      });
```

fetch request

```
fetch(url, {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify(requestPayload),           
    headers: {
        'Content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
        Authorization: 'Bearer ' + token,
    },
})
    // .then((response) => response.json()) .  // commit out this part if response body is empty
    .then((json) => {
        console.log("response :- ", json);
    }).catch((error)=>{
        console.log("Api call error ", error.message);
        alert(error.message);
});
```

Answer (score -2):

```
 transformRequest: [
  function(data, headers) {
    headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json";
    return JSON.stringify(data);
  }
]
```

try this, it works