# how i get response data from json with axios

Tags: reactjs, django-rest-framework

how i get response data and status header from json with axios?

whats wrong with my axios code?

my constructor:

```
class DetailProduct extends React.Component{

    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state = {
          dataOperations: [],
        isLoading: true
        };
      console.log(this.state.idf)

    axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/barang/select/', { id: 1 })
    .then(function(response){
      console.log(response.data)
      console.log(response.status)
    });  
    }
```

my Django rest framework:

```
class Selectitem(GenericAPIView):

    permission_classes = []

    def post(self, request):

        getb = Barang.objects.filter(pk = request.POST.get('id'))
        if getb.exists():
            f = getb.first()
            return Response({'nama_barang': f.nm_barang, 'harga_satuan': f.harga_satuan}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        else:
            return Response({"message": "What you were looking for isn't here."}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
    def get_serializer_class(self):
        return SelectItem
```

i can get data if using postman

[postman response data and status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tnRPC.png)

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Comment: yes, "xhr.js:178 XHR failed loading: POST "http://127.0.0.1:8000/barang/select/"." in my console

Comment: Try doing this you will get to know if it is giving some error     `axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/barang/select/', { id: 1 })
    .then(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
    });`

Comment: I have answered axios post here, Hope it will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47630163/axios-post-request-to-send-form-data/47630754#47630754

Answer (score 0):

Try doing it like this

```
const URL = `SOME_API_URL_THAT_YOU_TYPE_HERE`;
return axios({
  method: 'POST',
  url: URL,
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': `Bearer ${YOUR_TOKEN}`
  },
  data: {
    payload1: 'lorem',
    payload2: 'ipsum'
  },
})
.then(res => {
  console.log('Data', res.data);
 })
.catch(error => {
  console.log('Error', error.response.data);
 })
```