# How to send data correct axios Error: Multipart: Boundary not found

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios

I don't know why I receive on server **[Error: Multipart: Boundary not found]** 
and **bundle.js:37628 POST http://localhost:8800/exporttocsv 500 (Internal Server Error**)
When I make post through

```
<form action="/exporttocsv" method="POST"  encType="multipart/form-data">
```

post works correctly, but through `axios` doesn't work.

***Please help me fix the mistake***

this my code
/--client

```
import axios from 'axios'
var formData = new FormData()

const config = { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' } };
export const ipmortToCSV = (file) => dispatch => {

formData.append('file',file)
console.log(formData.getAll('data'))

axios.post('/exporttocsv', {
          "UploadCommand": formData
      },config)
      .then(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
```

//--server

```
const router = require('express').Router()
var csv = require('csv-express')
const controllers = require('../../controllers/exporttocsv')
var multer  = require('multer')
var upload = multer({dest : 'exporttocsv/'})

router.get('/', (req, res) => {
      controllers.exportToCsv(req,res)
  })
router.post('/',upload.single('file'),(req,res) => { 
    //controllers.importToCsv(req,res)
})

module.exports = router
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can do this ...

#### Instantiate a new `FormData` instance.

```
const config = { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' } };
let fd = new FormData();
fd.append('file',files[0])
return axios.post("http://localhost:5000/upload", fd, config)
```

#### Using`concat` and `concat-stream`

```
const concat = require("concat-stream")
const fd = new FormData()

fd.append("hello", "world")
fd.append("file", fs.createReadStream(file))
fd.pipe(concat(data => {
  axios.post("/hello", data, {
    headers: fd.getHeaders()
  })
}))
```

#### Using `promise`

```
const promise = new Promise((resolve) => {
  const fd = new FormData();
  fd.append("hello", "world");
  fd.append("file", fs.createReadStream(binaryFile));
  fd.pipe(concat({ encoding: 'buffer' }, data => resolve({ data, headers: fd.getHeaders() })));
});
promise.then(({ data, headers }) => axios.post('/hello', data, { headers }));
```

I hope I've been useful! :)

References:

- [github.com - Can't get a .post with Content-Type...](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/318)
- [github.com - Better solution using axios, form-data, fs](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/318#issuecomment-303392334)
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/47630754/3332734

Comment: HI, can you help me with this one ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54978454/passing-extra-values-by-post-to-another-function/54978732?noredirect=1#comment96716170_54978732

Comment: Sure, I hope that I can help you :)

Comment: What if you have more headers to add to the request?

Comment: @O'DaneBrissett which is? Can you give some examples? Keep in mind that this is a multipart formData, the reason I used Promises here. Any other key/value headers should be included before it. ;)

Answer (score 13):

I was struggling with this issue of multipart boundary not found with fetch api calling to a nestjs server. What I tried was to remove the

`'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'`,

headers so that Fetch api automatically set the headers and it worked. Try it out

Comment: I am using axios and i tried it there but it doesn't work as it seems axios defaults to application/json instead of recognizing the proper needed content type

Answer (score 5):

By default axios do not attach boundary to content type header. You have to do it manually:

```
axios.post(`${this.baseUrl}/${path}`, formData, {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': `multipart/form-data; boundary=${formData.getBoundary()}`,
      },
    })
```

It is especially important if you talking to spring server.

In other case you will see exception:

```
org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadException: the request was rejected because no multipart boundary was found
```

Comment: Tried this one. The warning disappeared but Laravel `Request::hasFile()` method can't detect uploaded file.

Comment: this worked for me recently.
but it might be related to an axios bug - https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/4631

Answer (score 2):

I was getting this problem with Axios via JavaScript because the content-type header was multipart-form-data but the boundary was missing.

Based on my research, a good way to handle it is to allow Axios to auto-detect the content type and set the headers correctly itself.

Here is an idea for how to accomplish this:

```
const formDataWithFiles = hasFiles ? new FormData() : undefined;

if (formDataWithFiles) {
    // axios will automatically set the content-type to multipart/form-data if the
    // data param is a FormData object
    // otherwise, it will use application/json
    // (study the Dev Tools > Network tab > XHR tab headers)
    Object.keys(modifiedFields)
        .forEach(field => formDataWithFiles.append(field, modifiedFields[field]));
}

const { data } = await axios({
    method,
    url: actionUrl,
    data: hasFiles ? formDataWithFiles : modifiedFields,
    headers: {
        ...axios.defaults.headers,
        ...headers,
    },
});

return data;
```

The above code is in a generic handleSubmit function that can be called from anywhere in the client-side.

Here is the function signature:

```
const { data } = await this.submitForm({
    actionUrl: this.actionUrl,
    method: this.method,
    modifiedFields: {
        ...this.modifiedUser,
    },
    hasFiles: true,
});
```

In the above code, there are two use cases. The first is the default case, where a normal payload is sent via a flat object. The second is the case when the form has files and you want `multipart/form-data`. In this case, we use the `FormData` Object as a vessel to instruct Axios to auto-detect the necessary headers and set the correct boundary.

If you do not specify the headers correctly, it is possible to receive an empty `$request->all()` Array in Laravel, or perhaps any server such as node.js.

The short answer to my answer is to use the `FormData` Object because it contains more information than a plain-old-JavaScript-object. With it, you can also access:

```
const formData = new FormData();

console.log('boundary:', formData._boundary);
```

As my annotation above hints towards, use the **Dev Tools > Network tab > XHR tab** to examine your request headers and make sure you have content-type `application/json` or `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` for regular form submits and `multipart/form-data'` if you are uploading a file.

Comment: Thank you. This is very helpful!

Answer (score 1):

For me add the following code to fixes it.

```js
axios.post('/xxx/Upload', formData, {
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
    },
    transformRequest: (data) => {
        return data
    },
})
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Answer (score 0):

For me the main reason was what the OP did; sending the `data` argument of `axios.post` as an object (`{ key: formDataObj}`) instead of just `formDataObj` directly as the arg.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I would like to share my solution as I struggled with this problem for almost a day. The issue was caused by an incorrect package version. Around 27.0.0, some changes were made to the form data sending, which resulted in issues with the boundaries. I'm not sure what version you folks are using, but it might be worth checking if this is the cause of your problem.

https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/4631

Answer (score 0):

Axios v0.27.x is not able to compute Boundary automatically of multipart/form-data. I was also facing the same issue.

**Kindly update your version to v1.x.x ( I am having v1.3.4 while writing the answer)**

Look in this thread for more detail -
https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/4631

Hope this will help you or somebody else. Thanks!

Happy Coding :-)