# Passing extra values by POST to another function

Tags: reactjs, express

I'm getting some troubles passing an `groupId` via post to my function to process it, basically I'm uploading a picture but I need to pass groupId to rename it picture on my other function, I'm using react and express to do this:

```
  onFormSubmit = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const { imageFile, currentGroupId } = this.state;
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('groupImage', imageFile);
    const config = {
      headers: {
        'content-type': 'multipart/form-data'
      }
    };
    await api.post('/fileUpload/group', { currentGroupId }, formData, config );
  }
```

My route:

```
router.post('/group', (req, res) => {
  fileuploadmanager.uploadFile(req, res);
});
```

And the backend side:

```
uploadFile(req, res) {
    const { uploadsPath } = this.porperties;
    const { currentGroupId } = req.body;//it prints but formData and config never comes here
    console.log("GROUP: ", currentGroupId);
    const storage = multer.diskStorage({
      destination: uploadsPath,
      filename: (req, file, cb) => {
        cb(null, `${file.fieldname}-${Date.now()}${path.extname(file.originalname)}`);
      },
    });

    const upload = multer({
      storage,
      limits: {
        fileSize: 1000000,
      },
      fileFilter: (req, file, cb) => {
        this.checkFileType(file, cb);
      },
    }).single('groupImage');

    upload(req, res, (err) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
    });
  }
```

Sending just `formData` and `config` works but it doesn't work if I add groupId to the endpoint. 
I tried appending it value in `formData` but I can't get it on the backend side, so now I trying passing it as a req.body, it works fine but my other paramters is not passing to the backend.

How can I pass my groupId, formData and config to my backend side?

**EDIT:** `api` is a wrapper to specify my backend URL. I'm using `axios`

```
import axios from 'axios';

export default axios.create({
  baseURL: process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL  
});
```

References:

- [How to send data correct axios Error: Multipart: Boundary not found](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49580158/3332734)

Comment: Whats `api.post`? I mean what are you using here? Probably this method doesn't take in extra param.

Comment: It's a axios class wrapper to especify my backend URL, it works.. anyway I updated the post with this wrapper.

Comment: First, you need to do two things: 1) debug the line `imageFile` and `currentGroupId` of  your `this.state`; ... 2) in your `config` property set headers like this `formData.getHeaders()`.

Comment: Next, post the results here

Answer (score 0):

Try sending all the data in one object `await api.post('/fileUpload/group', { currentGroupId, formData, config });`
Then get the data in `uploadFile(req, res) { const postData = req.body;`;
This should fix the issue.

Comment: I tried but I got `POST /api/v1/fileUpload/group 500 56.009 ms - 2320
TypeError: Cannot read property 'transfer-encoding' of undefined
`

Comment: `router.post('/group', (req, res) => {` this route and `api.post('/fileUpload/group'` are same?

Comment: Actually yes, because I have another file that prefix `fileUpload` to all my endpoints on this class, that's not the problem all data sends fine to my uploadFile function, the only problem is to sending an extra param in this case `currentGroupId`

Comment: Cool, `await api.post('/fileUpload/group', { currentGroupId, formData }, config);`
I put the config in the data too. Try this now.

Comment: Also do a `console.log(req.body)`

Comment: Alright I got this: `POST /api/v1/fileUpload/group - - ms - -
REQ:  {}
Error: Multipart: Boundary not found
    at new Multipart (/home/maudev/Escritorio/daily-tracking/backend/node_modules/busboy/lib/types/multipart.js:58:11)
`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189377/discussion-between-subhendu-kundu-and-maudev).