# Uploading a file from react to remote server

Tags: node.js, reactjs, multer

I am trying to upload a file every which way but I cannot get it to work. The client side code looks like this:

```
 var image = document.getElementById("upload").files[0];
```

I am grabbing the file in this way , I console log it and it works fine.

```
  const request = axios.post(PROJECTS_URL, {avatar: image});
```

I send the post request and get a status 500.
When I change the body of the post request to just text, and edit the server to take in text, it works fine.

I have also tried this:

```
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append("avatar", image, image.name)
const request = axios.post(PROJECTS_URL, formData);
```

for the server side code I am using multer and it looks like this:

```
app.post("/api", upload.single("avatar"), (req, res) => {

var entry = new Entry({
    img: req.file.path
})

entry.save().then((data) => {
    res.status(200).send(data)
}, (e) => {
    res.send(e)
})
})
```

I set up the multer middleware just not including it.
I am trying to upload an image to a mongodb database so I can later use the image url on the client side.
I am really stuck here and would appreciate any suggestions.

In my console on chrom i see 
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundarye2QF7dzzJWEGUjJE;
what is the boundary portion and is it preventing me from submiting the form?

Comment: What error text are you getting with the `500` response?

Comment: Status text says internal server error.

Comment: Alright. Have you tried changing your request to [how it is written in this accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47630163/axios-post-request-to-send-form-data)? Have you gotten it to work with e.g. Postman?

Comment: When I use postman i get a 200 and it returns the data. I changed the axios request method to match the one shown in the answer and i still get a 500 on the client side react project

Comment: In my console on chrom i see 
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundarye2QF7dzzJWEGUjJE;
what is the boundary portion and is it preventing me from submiting the form?

Comment: I'm not sure. If that is the only header that differs from your working Postman request, it might be worth looking into.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so the issue was with my server, i was not pushing to git with the uploads file. It helped a lot to look at the logs on heroku and from there i was getting an error message "no such file or directory". I have been using the git commit -am command so regularly that i just forgot to check git status and then i uploaded the uploads file.