# Axios sending my plain JSON with data-binary format

Tags: axios, http-status-code-400

When My Vuejs code try to post JSON, backend returned 400 error.

I found clue for that by chrome network capture.
My Axios code sended JSON with data-binary format.

```
curl 'http://localhost:5000/api/auth/login'  \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8' \
  -H 'Accept: application/json' \
  --data-binary '{"username":"admin","password":"ehllow"}'
```

But I don't know how it works like it.
My expecting request is

```
curl ... -D '{"username":"admin","password":"ehllow"}'`
```

not `--data-binary`

Here is my javascript code.

```
axios({
  method: 'post',
  url: '/api/auth/login',
  data: {
    "username": "admin",
    "password": "ehllow"
  },
  config: {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
  }
})
.then(function (response) {
  //handle success
  console.log(response);
})
.catch(function (response) {
  //handle error
  console.log(response);
});
```

How can I change my axios code to send json to normal Data(`-D`)

Comment: There's not enough information here to debug. What is the response text for the 400 status?

Comment: Also, there's nothing wrong with `--data-binary`. RTFM ~ _"This posts data exactly as specified with no extra processing whatsoever"_

Comment: FYI, there is no `config` option for axios requests and the default content-type is `application/json` anyway

Comment: You mean ``--data-binary``` is not problem.  I'll check back end codes.  Thank you.

Comment: Correct, it is not a problem at all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same question, answer was here:
[axios post request to send form data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47630163/axios-post-request-to-send-form-data)

In short:

```
let data = new FormData();
data.set("username", "admin");
data.set("password", "ehllow");
axios({
  method: 'post',
  url: '/api/auth/login',
  data: data,
  config: {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
  }
})
```

Threw me for a loop, as binary data is read differently than form data.