# axios post data as form data instead of as JSON in payload

Tags: reactjs, axios

I am just trying my first reactJS app.

In that I am using axios.post() method for sending data.

```
submitHandler = event => {
  event.preventDefault();
  axios
    .post("http://demo.com/api/v1/end-user/login", {
      username: "",
      password: "",
      user_type: 1
    })
    .then(res => {
      console.log(res);
      console.log(res.data);
    });
}
```

But when I check into my network tab, data which I am sending along with request is seems to be in payload.

[image]

I would like to send the data as form data instead. Am I am missing something?

Comment: The second argument is supposed to be stringified to JSON and used as the request payload. Is that not what you want?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to send the data as form data instead of as JSON in the payload, you can create a [`FormData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) object and use that as second argument instead.

```
submitHandler = event => {
  event.preventDefault();

  const formData = new FormData();
  formData.append("username", "");
  formData.append("password", "");
  formData.append("user_type", 1);

  axios.post("http://demo.com/api/v1/end-user/login", formData).then(res => {
    console.log(res);
    console.log(res.data);
  });
};
```

Comment: In node.js (not the browser) you can import `FormData` from the [`form-data` npm module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/form-data).

Comment: we might need `{ headers: { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' } }` after `formData`

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in axios by using FormData() like

```
var body = new FormData();
body.append('userName', 'test');
body.append('password', 'test');
body.append('user_type', 1);
```

And then you can use axios post method (You can amend it accordingly)

```
axios({
    method: 'post',
    url: 'http://demo.com/api/v1/end-user/login',
    data: body,
    config: { headers: {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' }}
    })
    .then(function (response) {
        //handle success
        console.log(response);
    })
    .catch(function (response) {
        //handle error
        console.log(response);
    });
```

Comment: No need to explicitly specify headers

Comment: Your second part is just copied from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47630754/16085086

Answer (score -1):

What worked for me is to send the form trough `params:` instead of `data:`

That way it will be send as GET variables instead of `Request Payload` and is much easier to read with `$_GET` in PHP. No idea how to send as post

```
axios({
    method: 'post',
    params: data,
    url: 'api.php',
  })
  .then((res) => {
    //Perform Success Action
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    // error.response.status Check status code
  }).finally(() => {
    //Perform action in always
  });
```