# NodeJS - FormData sends undefined values to server

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, axios, form-data

i am trying to send data to server with Form-Data and axios but it sends undefined values

for detecting that i tried to log all values in server and log formdata in client but server logged undefined values and client logged empty object 
here is my code

Client:

```
 handleFormSubmission(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var Data = new FormData();    

    Data.append('image', this.fileRef.current.files[0])
    Data.append('name', this.state.name);
    Data.append('time', this.state.time);
    Data.append('portion', this.state.portion);
    Data.append('ingredients', JSON.stringify(this.state.ingredients));
    Data.append('method', this.state.method);
    Data.append('level', this.state.level);
    Data.append('tags', JSON.stringify(this.state.tagsToSend));
      axios.post('/api/post-recipe', Data, {

     headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
     }
   }).then(res => res.data)
     .then(data =>{
      console.log(data.dish)
 })
 .catch(err => {
    if(err.response){
        if(err.response.data.redirect === true){
            window.location.replace(err.response.data.location)
        }
        if(err.response.data.message){
        alert(err.response.data.message)
        }
    }
 })
}
```

And Server:

```
 //multer part
 const storage = multer.diskStorage({

 destination: (req, file, callback) => {
 const userPath = path.join(imgStoragePath, req.userId);
 fs.mkdir(
  userPath,
  () => callback(null, userPath)
 )
 },

filename: (req, file, callback) => {
const filenameParts = file.originalname.split('.');
const ext = filenameParts.pop();
const basename = filenameParts.join('.');
const additionalPath = Date.now() + '' + uuid() + '' + 
Math.floor(Math.random() * (2000 - 500)) + 500;
callback(null, basename + '-' + additionalPath + '.' + ext);
}

})

const upload = multer({
storage,
limits: '1mb',
})

//route handling (i have validation in comments because there are some bugs too and i am concentrated on this problem)

 router.post('/', upload.single('image'), async (req, res) => {
 try {

const {
  name,
  time,
  portion,
  ingredients,
  method,
  level,
  tags
} = req.body
const { filename } = req.file;
 /* if (!req.file) {
  return res.status(409).send({
    message: 'გთხოვთ აირჩიოთ მინიმუმ 1 ფოტო'
  })
}



if (name.trim().length < 1) {
  return res.status(409).send({
    message: 'მიუთითეთ კერძის სახელი'
  })
}

if (time.trim().length < 1) {
  return res.status(409)({
    message: 'მიუთითეთ მომზადების დრო'
  })
}

if (!numberToTest.test(time)) {
  return res.status(409).send({
    message: 'დრო ჩაწერეთ ციფრების საშუალებით'
  })
}

if (portion.trim().length < 1) {
  return res.status(409).send({
    message: 'მიუთითეთ პორციის რაოდენობა'
  })
}

if (!numberToTest.test(portion)) {
  return res.status(409).send({
    message: 'პორცია ჩაწერეთ ციფრების საშუალებით'
  })
}

JSON.parse(ingredients).map(({
  ingredient,
  quantity
}) => {
  if (ingredient.trim().length < 1 || quantity.trim().length < 1) {
    return res.status(409).send({
      message: 'მიუთითეთ ინგრედიენტები სრულად'
    })
  }
})

if (method.trim().length < 20) {
  return res.status(409).send({
    message: '"მომზადების მეთოდი"-ს ველში უნდა იყოს მინიმუმ 20 ასო'
  })
}

if (!level == 'მარტივი' || level == 'საშუალო' || level == 'რთული') {
  return res.status(409).send({
    message: 'მიუთითეთ კერძის მომზადების სირთულე'
  })
}

if (JSON.parse(tags).length < 1) {
  return res.status(409).send({
    message: 'მიუთითეთ მინიმუმ 1 მონიშვნა (თეგი)'
  })
}

/*fs.readFile('../tags.json', 'utf8', function (err, content) {
  if (err) {
    return res.status(500).send({
      message: err.message
    })
  }

  const decodedContent = JSON.parse(content)

  if (!decodedContent.tags.includes(JSON.parse(tags))) {
    return res.status(409).send({
      message: 'მიუთითეთ ჩვენს მიერ შემოთავაზებული მონიშვნები (თეგები)'
    })
  }

})*/

 /*   var duplicateTagsGuard = Object.create(null);

for (var co = 0; co < tags.length; co++) {
  let val = tags[co];

  if (val in duplicateTagsGuard) {
    return res.status(409).send({
      message: 'ნუ გამოიყენებთ ერთ მონიშვნას (თაგს) რამდენჯერმე'
    })
  }

  duplicateTagsGuard[val] = true

}
*/

const user = await User.findById(req.userId, '-password -_id -email -loginAttmepts -lockUntil').lean();

const dish = await Dish.create({
  author: user.username,
  name: name,
  time: time,
  portion: portion,
  ingredients: JSON.parse(ingredients),
  method: method,
  level: level,
  tags: JSON.parse(tags),
  createdAt: 'Date- ' + new Date().toLocaleDateString() + ' Time- ' + new Date().toLocaleTimeString()
})

console.log('დიში ' + dish.toObject())


return res.status(200).send({
  dish: JSON.stringify(dish)
})




} catch (error) {
return res.status(500).send({
  message: error.message
  })
 }
})
```

and log is:

```
name undefined time undefined portion undefined ingredients undefined method undefined level undefined tags undefined
```

what is problem? how can i solve it

Comment: Can you try removing the content type header?

Comment: of course, 1 min

Comment: nope, it did not work

Comment: before you send the formData , put a console.log to see that those values are defined, maybe the "problem" is on the React side

Comment: instead of sending Data i send just `name` variable and it logged in server side

Comment: so you found the problem..?

Comment: no i did not. when i am sending `Data` it sends undefined values but when i send `name` variable  it logs name, so only thing i get is that problem is in formData

Comment: It's possible that there is a binding problem of "this". Do you make sure the "this" is bound to the React component class?

Comment: yes, problem is not that

Comment: do you got any idea?

Comment: can you edit the code, so it shows the entire function from which the ajax is sent? all of it

Comment: ajax? i am using axios

Comment: there is nothing more but i still edited

Comment: I dont know :-(

Comment: also there is one factor too. when i posted the code here it logged undefined but before that in my server side i was saving that form data in database and it was saving and giving me data that i saved so like if i send data name: 'blah' portion: '1' and etc. it was saving that so in that case server was getting data and this is so confusing

Comment: if you wish i can post that code too

Comment: Seems that maybe you have some logical problem with your React state..because you're saying that sometimes it works, and sometimes it doesn't. I would place a debugger statement in the code, and use the dev-tools step by step to see what's going on. And yes, post whatever code you have

Comment: i am really confused, i deleted multer part from my code and it did not work i added it back and it sent data to server i don't know what is happening so i will edit and post full backend code

Comment: by the way when my jwt token expires and i try to send data to server it  gives me error ERR_CONNECTION_ABORTED or ERR_CONNECTION_RESET and when i delete file to send it redirects me sign in page (it must do it)

Comment: I see that this data is handled in a route "/". But in your front end, you're sending it to /api/post-recipe. Are you sure you're using the correct function...?

Comment: yeah that is correct because i am using `router.use('/api/post-recipe', require('postrecipe.js'))`

Answer (score 1):

`upload.single('image')` may filter out the request body since its not an image content-type, but from the comments it appears the issue may be elsewhere.

Checking around it looks like `append` seems to be for adding binary entities vs `set` for form fields - see
[axios post request to send form data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47630163/axios-post-request-to-send-form-data)

Comment: i changed append to set and it gave me error :net::ERR_CONNECTION_ABORTED

Comment: @ilia1 is the webserver crashing / aborting the connection?

Comment: no but before i tried this, connection errors occur when i sent request after my jwt token expired

Comment: @ilia1 one thing I do sometimes to debug exactly what is happening is run this in the node.js repl; `new net.Server((s) => {s.on('data', d => process.stdout.write(d));} ).listen(3000)`. Point the UI at "localhost:3000" for the request and it will write out the raw request. I'm suggesting this because I'm not sure what is being sent to the server exactly. If you can edit your post to include the raw HTTP output we may be able to help more.