# axios doesnt post data to server

Tags: php, reactjs, axios

I am trying to make a login validation form in React and i am using axios to make database calls.

The thing is, i make contact with the server - i get 200 response but the data i post is not there.

This is what i did the first time:

```
const user = {username: this.state.username, password: this.state.password}
axios.post("http://localhost:80/thinksmart/post_requests/login.php", user)
.then(res => console.log(res))
.catch(err => console.log(err))
```

Then i tried another approach - where i set up base url :

```
const api = axios.create({baseURL: 'http://localhost:80'})
    api.post("/thinksmart/post_requests/login.php", user)
    .then(response => {
        console.log(response)
    })
    .catch(error => 
        console.log(error)
    )
```

and neither of these worked.

In PHP i only do this:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type'); 
echo json_encode($_POST);
```

and i get an empty array even though i have data sent (the user data)

Comment: Maybe `this.state.username` and `this.state.password` are `null` ?

Comment: I checked (simple console.log) and they were set to the value of the form.

Comment: Can you go to the `Network` part on the chrome dev console and see if the data is rightly posted ? If so, then it's the server who badly handle the data.

Comment: It says request payload is set and it is correct (carries values of username and pass)

Comment: on the server side im not doing anything at all except for outputting the $_POST superglobal contents

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can solve this issue in two ways:
1- **PHP code changes**: to get the JSON data in the backend you need to execute the following code instead of the `$_POST`:

```
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
```

2- **Javascript code changes**: To be able to receive the data in the backend using `$_POST` you need to send it using `FormData` more details can  be found in the following link:
[axios post requests using form-data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47630163/axios-post-request-to-send-form-data)