# Axios request not receiving formData with content-type set

Tags: javascript, redux, axios, multipartform-data, form-data

I have the following data being added to my `formData()`

```
let uploadData = new FormData();
uploadData.append("peer-video", this.state.peerVideo);
uploadData.append("peer-video-thumbnail", this.state.peerVideoThumbnail);
uploadData.append("project-video", this.state.projectVideo);
uploadData.append(
  "project-video-thumbnail",
  this.state.projectVideoThumbnail
);
this.state.documents.forEach(item => {
  uploadData.append("documents", item);
});
```

The `uploadData` has key value pairs in it, I did `formData.entries()` to check this. And my axios request is as follows:

```
   export const addProject = data => dispatch => {
  axios
    .post("/api/portfolio/add-project", data, {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": `multipart/form-data`
      }
    })
    .then(res => {
      dispatch({
        type: ADD_PROJECT,
        payload: res.data
      });
    })
    .catch(err => {
      dispatch({
        type: ADD_PROJECT,
        payload: err
      });
    });
};
```

And if I go to my payload in the network tab I see this:

```
{"uploadData":{}}
```

Any suggestions? Thank you for taking the time to help me.

**Edit**
I tried the following structure in my axios request and it yielded the same result.

```
axios({
    method: "post",
    url: "/api/portfolio/add-project",
    data: data,
    config: { headers: { "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data" } }
  })
```

When I execute the following

```
   for (let keys of uploadData.entries()) {
      console.log(keys);
    }
```

These are the values:
[image]

I also noticed on [formData docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append) that

> > Note: If you specify a Blob as the data to append to the FormData object, the filename that will be reported to the server in the "Content-Disposition" header used to vary from browser to browser.

But i'm not sure if that's what is causing my issue here?

Comment: Send data: { asdf: “zzz” } and let us now if it works. From the code you posted it’s normal to think you are again sending empty objects and logging to console the content of uploadData rather than data. Please edit your question to the actual code you are running!!!

Comment: Let me know if there's anything I missed, I updated my question after you posted your answer. 

I hard coded the data like this `uploadData.append("data", { asdf: "test" });` 

And the axios request still is empty

Comment: No ... where you make the axios request the data you send is highlighted by the key data and the value should be uploadData. You are sending axios({“data”: data}) which is incorrect because there is no data variable

Comment: AHHHHHHHH hahah, I feel like a dunce! I see what you are saying. The function I am calling addProjects is being passed an object and not the actual freaking form... WOW

Comment: Does it work now that you are sending the correct data ? If it does can you accept the answer I posted originally ? Cheers !

Comment: @vortex, I accepted your answer my man. I gotcha =], thanks again

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Looks like you are posting an undefined variable called data rather than your uploadData

Comment: Its supposed to be the comment, not an answer.

Comment: That’s if you assume OP made a typo

Comment: Agree, but we can get it clarified in comments section itself and then show the right way to do it.

Comment: I updated my post to make it clear to what data I passed to axios

Comment: I am sorry the answer doesn’t satisfy you, however it’s supposed to be OP decision. If you want to justify the “we” in your previous comment then you are free to edit my answer and pinpoint the issue with code blocks. Going off topic or bickering about won’t improve anything

Comment: @user10204157 when you post to the add-project route I see the data sent variable as being called “data” whereas the variable you create and populate with entries is called “formData” - I don’t see anything changed in that regard. Is this correct ?

Comment: I pass uploadData in as data into the add-project route.

I updated my question with the entire function itself. I wanted to leave it out so I didn't bring Redux into this. My apologies.

Comment: @user10204157 possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47630163/axios-post-request-to-send-form-data then. If you are truly using the correct variables the boundary or web server antics you are facing is niche - while you edited the code to reflect your actual function now you skipped the part where you actually execute the post. At this point I would send some hardcoded values just to make sure I can POST

Comment: I tried the suggested duplicate and it is still happening. I tested my POST route already all of that is fine.

--Thanks for giving your input and making sure i'm checking all of this

Answer (score 1):

Welp, this is what happens when your eyes stare at a screen too long.

```
  this.props.addProject({
      title: this.state.title,
      company: this.state.company,
      description: this.state.description,
      role: this.state.role,
      skills: this.state.skills,
      uploadData: uploadData
    });
```

Needed to simply be:
`this.props.addProject(uploadData)`

Thank you @vortex

[image]