# FormData server side NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, web-applications, form-data

I'm developing a web application using nodejs server-side. I'm trying to send pdf files from client to server.

Client:

```
var files = new FormData();
var count = 0;
$('#tableSlideId tr').each(function() {

    var inputForm = $(this).find("th:first").children();
    file = inputForm[0].files[0];
    files.append((count++).toString(),file);

});

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/sendFiles",
    data: files,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,

}).done(function(err){

    var text ="";
    if(err) {

        text = "Upload FAILED! Retry ...";

    } else {

        text = "Upload SUCCES!";

    }

    alert(text);



});
```

I think the client side is ok, infact if I use this loop:

```
for(var p of files)
  console.log(p);
```

I correctly visualize all the elements that I want to send to the server.

Server:

```
app.post('/sendFiles', function(req,res) {

    console.log("--->",req.body);
    res.end();

});
```

Now in the server I have no idea how to visualize the data that I send, infact req.body is empty.

I don't know if this is the right way but my goal is to load some pdf files form the client, send to the server and after store them in a mySql dmbs.
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [express-formidable](https://github.com/utatti/express-formidable) module. install 'express-formidable' by the running command

```
npm install express-formidable --save
```

a simple example is as follows from github

```
const express = require('express');
const formidable = require('express-formidable');

var app = express();

app.use(formidable());

app.post('/upload', (req, res) => {
  //req.fields contains non-file fields 
  //req.files contains files 
  console.log(req.fields);
  console.log(req.files);
});
```

Hope this helps!

Edit, from [here](https://flaviocopes.com/express-forms-files/) -

```
app.post('/submit-form', (req, res) => {
  new formidable.IncomingForm().parse(req, (err, fields, files) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error('Error', err)
      throw err
    }
    console.log('Fields', fields)
    console.log('Files', files)
    files.map(file => {
      console.log(file)
    })
  })
})
```

Comment: It seems that it doesn't work. Now my client isn't able to connect with server and server side I have this error:
Error: Request aborted
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\Universita\Magistrale\ProgrammazioneDistribuita\Progetto\sourcecode\node_modules\formidable\lib\incoming_form.js:122:19)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:189:13)
    at abortIncoming (_http_server.js:449:9)
    at socketOnClose (_http_server.js:442:3)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:194:15)
    at TCP._handle.close (net.js:597:12)

Comment: Try using enctype="multipart/form-data" in html like <form id="upload_form" enctype="multipart/form-data">. Let me know if any errors.

Comment: enctype="multipart/form-data" doesn't fix the previous error

Comment: If this does not work then I recommend you to user axios library in client application. Sending form data in axios is pretty straight forward. Look at this question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47630163/axios-post-request-to-send-form-data

Comment: I solve using this schema:

const formidable = require('formidable');

app.post('/sendFiles', function(req,res) {

        new formidable.IncomingForm().parse(req, (err, fields, files) => {
            if (err) {
              console.error('Error', err)
              throw err
            }
            
            console.log('Files', files);
 
          })

  

        res.end();

    });

I follow this link https://flaviocopes.com/express-forms-files/

Answer (score 0):

I think you need some middleware to accept the multipart formdata in the server side. Multer is a good option.

You can use

```
var multer  = require('multer')
var upload = multer({ dest: 'uploads/' })
```

and then update your server side to handle the upload:

```
app.post('/sendFiles', upload.array('files', maxCount), function(req,res)
```