# redux saga is not fetching user data

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm trying to make an api call to the saga function `export function* userLogin`. However all im getting back is **bad request** on the network server.

I'm not able to see the `console.log` within this function.

```
export function* userLogin(action){
    try{
        const user = yield call(api.user.loginUser, action.data);
        console.log(user);
        const token = user.token
        console.log(token);
        // pass the token in session

        sessionStorage.setItem("jwtToken", token);
        setAuthToken(token);
        const decoded = jwt_decode(token);
        // pass the decoded token
        // dispatch(setCurrentUser(decoded))
        // yield put(userLogInSuccess(user));
        yield put( userLogInSuccess(decoded))
    }
    catch(error){
        yield put(userLogInFailure(error.response.data));
    }
}
export function* watchUserLogIn() {
    yield takeLatest(LOGIN_USER, userLogin);
}


export default function* () {
    yield fork(watchUserLogIn);
}
```

**api call**

```
import Axios from './Axios';

export default {
    user:{
        loginUser: userData => 
            Axios.post('/users/login', {userData}).then(res => res.data.token)
    }
};
```

**actions**

```
export const loginUser = (userData) => {
    return {
      type: LOGIN_USER,
      userData
    };
  }

export const userLogInSuccess = token => ({
    type: USER_LOG_IN_SUCCESS,
    token
})

export const userLogInFailure = error => ({
    type: USER_LOG_IN_FAILURE,
    error
})
```

**Login.js**

```
 .....
 handleSubmit = (e) => {
     e.preventDefault();
     const {formData} = this.state;
     const {username, password} = formData;
     const creds = {
        username,
        password
     }
 this.props.loginUser(creds);


 // console.log(creds);
}
 ...
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    auth: state.auth
})
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
    loginUser: (userData) => dispatch(loginUser(userData)),

})
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Login)
```

**Axios.js**

```
import Axios from 'axios';
import 'dotenv/config';

let AxiosInstance = Axios.create({
    baseURL: process.env.REACT_APP_BASE_URL,  // localhost:3000
    withCredentials: true,
    headers : {
      'Content-Type' : 'application/json',
      'Accept' : 'application/json',
    }

  })



 AxiosInstance.interceptors.response.use(function(response) {
    // const token = localStorage.getItem('auth');
    // response.headers.Authorization =  token ? `Bearer ${token}` : '';
    // console.log(token);
    return response;
 })

export default AxiosInstance
```

old thunk code.

```
// export const loginUser = userData => dispatch => {
//     Axios.post('/users/login', userData)
//         .then( res => {
//             // retrieve token from the response 
//             const token = res.data.token;
//             // console.log(token);
//             // pass the token in session
//             sessionStorage.setItem("jwtToken", token);
//             // set the auth token
//             setAuthToken(token);

//             // decode the auth token
//             const decoded = jwt_decode(token);
//             // pass the decoded token
//             dispatch(setCurrentUser(decoded))

//         })
//         .catch(err => {
//             if(err.response.data){
//                 console.log(err.response)
//                 dispatch({
//                     type: GET_ERRORS,
//                     payload: err.response.data
//                 })
//             }
//         })
// }
```

Comment: What is Axios module? And what is the error that is returned from the server?

Comment: Bad request is the error.

Comment: the Axios module is just the baseUrl of localhost:3000 is all. ill share it.

Comment: http://localhost:3000/users/login 400 bad request

Comment: That error is usually that the wrong data type is sent, try changing the post call to:
`{ ...userData }` or just `userData`.

Comment: console.log(api.user.loginUser) gives me `userData => _Axios__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__["default"].post('/users/login', {
      userData
    }).then(res => res.data.token)`

Comment: The Axios works, i used it on thunk. but here im converting it to a saga function ill post the working logic of how it would be if was on thunk.

Comment: Make sure that `action.data` is an object like `{ username: "foo", password: "bar" }` and that the POST request has that data.
Also, check how the server receiver that data, it could be as JSON or a [FormData](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47630163/axios-post-request-to-send-form-data).

Comment: does the actions look right.

Comment: Looks like you need to use `action.userData` in your saga, instead of `action.data`. `yield call(api.user.loginUser, action.userData);`

Comment: let me give that a shot.

Comment: still getting bad request.

Comment: But your thunk worked?

Comment: The way your passing userData inside of your `api call` is also different than the Thunk was. In the thunk you were passing in `Axios.post('/users/login', userData)` but in the `api call` it's `Axios.post('/users/login', {userData})`. Try switching it to just pass in userData.

Comment: it is moving forward now, i just removed the brackets on the api call so instead of `{userData }` just `userData`

Comment: The difference is `{ userData: { username, password }}` vs `{ username, password }`

Comment: Yeah, you've probably been sending requests with no payload the entire time, oops :)

Comment: Thanks Cory Appreciate the assistance. Did you want to make an answer, so i can accept ?

Comment: Despite the fact that i have another error now, but its progress though.

Comment: the back end  makes  a 200 post request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 things I noticed, while comparing the Saga code to your Thunk:

1. The saga is passing `action.data` into your api call instead of `action.userData`. userData is returned from the action.
2. The api call is passing `{userData}` to the request instead of `userData`. This means you're sending along `{ userData: { username, password } }` rather than `{ username, password }`