# 400 Bad Request from Axios to Django, field is required

Tags: javascript, python, django, django-rest-framework, axios

I'm trying to send a POST request from my React frontend using Axios

```
import axios from 'axios'
axios.post('http://server:port/auth/login', {
    username: 'admin', 
        password: 'MY_PASSWORD', 

}, {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'
        }
})
.then(response => { 
    console.log(response)
})
.catch(error => {
    console.log(error.response)
});
```

No matter what I do, I get a 400 Bad Request in response stating:

```
"username":[This field is required],
"password":[This field is required]
```

[image: Image of the error]

I am using the [Django REST framework](https://github.com/davesque/django-rest-framework-simplejwt) in my Django Backend for authentication.

Everything works fine using Insomnia but any requests through React results in a "Bad Request"

[image: Insomnia]

django-cors-headers has been installed and configured as well.

Comment: Can you check the exact headers in insomnia and see the difference with ones you use in axios? Maybe...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [axios post request to send form data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47630163/axios-post-request-to-send-form-data)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering my own question here.

Setting the parser to `JSONParser` solved the issue.

Setting it projectwide is the best option -

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PARSER_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.parsers.JSONParser',
    ]
}
```

Also set the header to json while sending request from Axios.

```
headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}
```

Thankyou who tried to help!