# 400 bad Request using axios, flask and react

Tags: python, reactjs, flask, react-redux, axios

I am unable to make post request via react js to python-flask server.
I am using axios. This request works on postman, but I can't seem to figure out why I can make post request from my react app.

Please see flask code:

```
@app.route('/match_home_types', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def match_home_types():
    area = request.form['area']

    response = jsonify({
        'home_types': util.match_area_with_types(area)
    })

    response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')

    return response
```

My react-redux action code:

```
export const matchHouseTypes = (area) => (dispatch) => {
  axios
    .post("http://127.0.0.1:5000/match_home_types", area)
    .then((res) => {
      dispatch({
        type: MATCH_TYPES,
        payload: res.data.home_types,
      });
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error.response);
    });
};
```

my react class component:

```
  get_house_types = () => {
    const { selectedOption } = this.state;
    if (selectedOption == "Find a location") {
      alert("Please select a valid location");
    }
    var area = {
      area: selectedOption.replace(/(^\w|\s\w)/g, (m) => m.toUpperCase()),
    };
    console.log("area:", area);
    this.props.matchHouseTypes(area);
  };
```

See below error response from axios:

```
data: "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">↵<title>400 Bad Request</title>↵<h1>Bad Request</h1>↵<p>The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.</p>↵"
status: 400
statusText: "Bad Request"
```

Please assist

Comment: I think you need to use FormData. Please refer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47630163/axios-post-request-to-send-form-data

Comment: thanks the link was helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was that I was not sending the API parameters the right way. Since I am sending via form data I changed my code from:

```
 var area = {
      area: selectedOption.replace(/(^\w|\s\w)/g, (m) => m.toUpperCase()),
    };
```

to:

```
  const formData = new FormData();
          formData.append(
            "area",
            selectedOption.replace(/(^\w|\s\w)/g, (m) => m.toUpperCase())
          );
```

complete function:

```
  get_house_types = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const { selectedOption } = this.state;
    if (selectedOption == "Find a location") {
      alert("Please select a valid location");
    } else {
      const formData = new FormData();
      formData.append(
        "area",
        selectedOption.replace(/(^\w|\s\w)/g, (m) => m.toUpperCase())
      );
      this.props.matchHouseTypes(formData);
    }
  };
```