# Converting cURL command to JavaScript

Tags: node.js, axios

I'm trying to call an Instagram API call from my server (nodeJS) and I am not sure how to do so.

```
curl -X POST https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token \
  -F client_id=123456... \
  -F client_secret=123abc... \
  -F grant_type=authorization_code \
  -F redirect_uri=https://google.sg/ \
  -F code=123abc
```

This command returns the desired output when I run it on the command line, but I can't seem to find a way to do the same in JavaScript. Here is what I've tried:

```
axios
  .post("https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token", {
    client_id: 123456...,
    client_secret: "123abc...",
    grant_type: "authorization_code",
    redirect_uri: "https://google.sg",
    code:
      "123abc...",
  })
```

This is what is logged in by the catch block:

```
data: {
  error_type: 'OAuthException',
  code: 400,
  error_message: 'Missing required field client_id'
}
```

I think `-F` refers to form data, but I can't seem to find a way to do that in axios.

edit: I've tried it with just `client_id`, and it returns the same error.

edit 2: I don't think this is a fix but Postman Agent has a nifty function to translate the HTTP request into code:
[image]

It can be accessed via `Code` on the right.

Comment: use body to send the data. fetch(..., { body: { client_id:..,... }})

Comment: This might help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47630163/axios-post-request-to-send-form-data

Comment: I tried this, and it returns 500 internal server error. Without the header though, it returns 400 missing required field.

Answer (score 0):

Just see that in your CURL request you have the redirect_uri: `https://google.sg/`

And in your axios params you have: `https://google.sg`

You are missing a `/` in the axios parameter.

The way Oauth2 works is that it appends parameters to the redirect_uri specified in your api settings, so if you set it to `https://google.sg/`, it is expected that it is indeed the same url, without any changes.

The response you should be getting would be:
`https://google.sg/access_token=#xxxx`

As you had specified, the response would be different, like so:

`https://google.sg?access_token=#xxxx`

That is not only a non-valid URL, but it also doesn't match the one you specified.

For this reason it is recommended that you set a standard path, for example:

`https://google.sg/oauth`

So in the end you would get:

`https://google.sg/oauth?access_token=#xxxx`