# How to POST form data with axios?

Tags: javascript, http, axios

I'm trying to set up post requests using Axios. The post request gets sent and received but I want to make it so that whatever I put into the text box gets sent in the said post request.

(This is my first time using Javascript and node.js and using CSS please keep such in mind)

my HTML:

````
 <form action="/Stanza" method="post"></form>
          <input class="btn btn-primary mx-auto h-8 app-title mt-2 bg-purple-600 rounded-lg p-4 text-center overflow-hidden xl:my-4 xl:px-4 w-1/6 placeholder-white" id="setPrize" type="text" onchange="updatevariable(stanza)" onclick="setStanza();" placeholder="Enter a stanza"/>
          <input class="btn btn-primary mx-auto h-8 app-title mt-2 bg-purple-600 rounded-lg p-4 text-center overflow-hidden xl:my-4 xl:px-4 w-1/6 placeholder-white" onclick="gay2();" placeholder="Jid/@">Victim</button>
         <input class="btn btn-warning mx-auto h-8 app-title mt-2 bg-purple-600 rounded-lg p-4 text-center overflow-hidden xl:my-4 xl:px-4 w-1/6" id="prize" type="text" onclick="clearOutput()"/>
            <div class="panel-body" id="getResult1"></div>```
````

My axios:

```
let stanza = "";

 function setStanza(value){
    stanza = value;
}

onchange="setStanza(this.​value)"

let victim = 'gay';

var element = document.getElementById("myInput");
element.onchange = axios.post('/Stanza', {stanza})
.then(function gay (response) {
  console.log(response);
  console.log(element.value);
})
.catch(function gay2 (error) {
  console.log(error);
});
```

My express:

```
app.post('/Stanza', function(req, res) {
    console.log('receiving data ...');
    console.log('body is ',req.body);
    res.send(req.body);
});
```

Comment: nice function names

Comment: That isn't CSS at all by the way, it's HTML

Comment: Does this answer your question? [axios post request to send form data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47630163/axios-post-request-to-send-form-data)

Comment: @Laif was using Tailwind CSS for the classes my bad it's the first thing I'm actually making involving any CSS it's kind of a crutch thank you btw

Comment: @AlwaysHelping Sadly no.

Comment: @BaconBacon this doesn't involve any CSS

Comment: @Laif I was having a brain-fart excuse me xD