# Firebase Functions Axios RangeError: Maximum Call Stack Size Exceeded

Tags: javascript, axios, google-cloud-functions

I am building a Firebase cloud function that connects to merchant's website and requests a PaymentIntent object.

I'm submitting the API call via axios:

```
exports.getPaymentIntent = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
    // Initialise dependencies
    const axios = require('axios')
    const FormData = require('form-data')

    // Assemble payload
    let formData = new FormData()
    formData.append('amount', '10.99')
    ...

    try {
        const response = await axios.post('merchant.com/getPaymentIntent', formData, {
            headers: {
                'X-API-KEY': 'myPrivateKey'
            }
        })

        return response
    } catch (error) {
        return error
    }
})
```

When I run the function, it crashes with the following axios error:

> Unhandled error RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

I can't find out why this is happening. Removing the headers from the request doesn't change the error message either.

Is there anything I can try to fix this please?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution few answers deep [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53126159/2874028).

I had to add an additional header in the request (on top of the `X-API-KEY` header):

`'Content-Type': multipart/form-data; boundary=${formData._boundary}`.

Setting it as just `multipart/form-data` would not work, so make sure you include the boundary.

Answer (score 0):

I was having same issue, and in my case I fixed by returning response.data instead of just response. Seems that the response object is huge and Firebase breaks when try to parse it. You can confirm that by running `console.log(response)`.