# React JS CORS-ORIGIN - Instagram Basic Display API

Tags: reactjs, cors, instagram, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

I have problem with `CORS: Access-Control-Allow-Origin` when try to exchange the code for access token from Instagram API.

Instagram API documentation Step 5 : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api/getting-started#step-5--exchange-the-code-for-a-token

Body parameters:

```
const body = {
    'client_id': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    'client_secret': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    'grant_type': 'authorization_code',
    'redirect_uri': 'https://localhost:3000/',
    'code': instaCode
};
```

My request:

```
axios.post(`https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token`, qs.stringify(body), { 
     headers: {'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'} 
});
```

Тhis code worked 2 months ago.

Answer (score 0):

edit: you can try this [axios post request to send form data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47630163/axios-post-request-to-send-form-data) first which seems better, below worked for me though

That won't work, you have to send the body in a form data.

I believe fetch API would work but that's available since node 17, if you're using earlier version this is what worked for me.

SOURCE https://www.section.io/engineering-education/integrating-instagram-basic-display-api/

```
const { post } = require("request");
const { promisify } = require("util");


const postAsync = promisify(post);

    const form = {
        client_id: NUMBER,
        client_secret: STRING,
        grant_type: "authorization_code",
        redirect_uri: STRING,
        code: req.body.code,
    };

    let { body, statusCode } = await postAsync({
        // let result = await postAsync({
        url: "https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token",
        form,
        headers: {
            "content-type": "multipart/form-data",
            host: "api.instagram.com",
        },
    });
```

npm i request
and use that inside a try/catch of course

Answer (score 0):

I have wasted 3 days on this error but finally got the solution.

You cannot handle it from front-end side because Instagram API only accepts requests from one medium and for that you will have to deploy your API at backend to resolve this issue.

Once you will deploy the API at backend and backend will request for the access_token , your issue will be resolved.