# Axios package's POST request is unable to post the data sent as JSON or form data to a REST end point

Tags: node.js, rest, post, axios, arcgis

I am replacing the deprecated 'request' package of npm with 'axios' latest in Node 16.15.x application.

However, I am facing an issue with one POST request sent via axios (other POST requests I was able to implement)

Here is code using 'request' package POST

```
request.post('https://sampleserver6.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/tokens/generateToken', {
    form: {
        'username': 'user1',
        'password': 'user1',
        'client': 'requestip',
        'expiration': 60,
        'f': 'json',
    }
}, (err, response, body) => {
    console.log('****Token', body)
})
```

This gives the expected response. Which is a token. I am using a sample REST server "https://sampleserver6.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/tokens/generateToken"

Now when trying the same POST request using 'axios' POST,

```
axios.post('https://sampleserver6.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/tokens/generateToken', {
        'username': 'user1',
        'password': 'user1',
        'client': 'requestip',
        'expiration': 60,
        'f': 'json',
    }, {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'
        }
    })
    .then(function(response) {
        console.log('****Token', body)
    })
```

The response is 200 however the response data shows an error as "Invalid request Usage: [https://sampleserver6.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/tokens?request=gettoken&username=username&password=password&"](https://sampleserver6.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/tokens?request=gettoken&username=username&password=password&%22)

This is the same error on the [sample REST server](https://sampleserver6.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/tokens/generateToken) as well when you put no values/partial values in the form and click 'Generate Token'.
So it seems 'axios' is not able to put form data as expected.

Am I using the correct implementation in 'axios' POST?

I have tried using the 'form-data' package as well -> same error

I have tried different Content-Type -> Issue persists

Comment: You can find the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47630163/axios-post-request-to-send-form-data) on the usage of Form data with Axios

Comment: I will give it another try. Thanks

Comment: I was able to work it out with the help of URLSearchParams

Answer (score 1):

Using `URLSearchParams` instead of `FormData` worked for me.

```
const param = new URLSearchParams({
  'username': 'user1',
  'password': 'user1',
  'client': 'requestip',
  'expiration': 60,
  'f': 'json',
});

axios({
  method: 'post',
  url: 'https://sampleserver6.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/tokens/generateToken',
  data: param.toString()
});
```

P.S: Did not have to pass any headers.

Answer (score -1):

Your `Content-Type` value is wrong. you are sending a JS object so the content type should be `application/json`; however, I will advise that you let the library determine that value. You can always inspect the request with your navigator dev tools to verify the content type value. Nevertheless, this should work:

```
axios
  .post('https://sampleserver6.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/tokens/generateToken', {
        username: 'user1',
        password: 'user1',
        client: 'requestip',
        expiration: 60,
        f: 'json',
    })
    .then(({data}) {
        console.log('****Token', data)
    })
```

or

```
const form = new FormData() //generally used to upload files
form.append('username', 'user1');
form.append('password', 'user1');
form.append('client', 'requestip');
form.append('expiration', 60);
form.append('f', 'json');

axios
  .post('https://sampleserver6.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/tokens/generateToken', form)
    .then(({data}) {
        console.log('****Token', data)
    })
```