# Form submission React , axios , useForm

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, use-form

Using useForm need to create a form where, for example, 3 inputs, 2 types of text ('name' and 'email') and 1 file ('photo'). When the button is clicked, so the post is submitted, a POST request must be made to the URL via **axios** with a specific header ('Token').

The problem is that in data I have what is in the photo below (photo length: 0), so the request is not proceed.

```
            <form className='main__post-form' onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
            <label> Name
                <input autoComplete='off'
                    {...register('name', {
                        required: true,
                    })}
                />
            </label>
            <label> Email
                <input autoComplete='off'
                    {...register('email', {
                        required: true,
                    })}
                />
            </label>
            <label> Picture
                <input type='file' accept='.jpg, .jpeg'
                       {...register('photo', {
                           required: true,
                       })}
                />
            </label>
           <button className='main__post-submit' type='submit'>Submit</button>
        </form>
```

so on submit:

```
const onSubmit = (data) => {
    axios.post('some url there', data, {
        headers: {
            'Token': token,
        }
        }).then((res) => {console.log('ok', res)}).catch((err) => {console.log('error', err)})
    reset()
}
```

[image]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I think you might want to look at [this answer to a similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47630754/7018960)

Comment: i wanna rly see the complete example of this case, because in those themes the solution was very hard to understand and i don't get it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please add content type header in axios and try `"Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"`

Comment: no, it's not working idk(

Comment: Please try this. https://codesandbox.io/s/nice-engelbart-4bcded

Comment: thx, this is smth but what about the other fields for example name?

Comment: The name also you will get in the data.  I have updated the example. http://codesandbox.io/s/nice-engelbart-4bcded `const onSubmit = async (data: any) => {
    const formData = new FormData();
    console.log(data);`