# I am trying to upload image to the nodejs api using React js and i need help how to upload

Tags: reactjs, image, api, axios

create async thunk: [image]
this is my node js api route
`router.post('/', upload.single('image'), protect, setAd)`

this is my react js code
`export const sellBike = (bikeData) => API.post("/", bikeData);`

my react js api
`const API = axios.create({baseURL:"http://localhost:8000"});`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

example from my project:

1. convert img to string

> img.toDataURL()

2. Post to backend

> const saveAvatar = () =>
> axios.post<string[]>(`http://${DOMAIN}/profile/saveAvatar/${id}`,   {
> avatar
> }
> );

3. Take and save

   > profile.post('/saveAvatar/:id', async (req, res) => {   try  {
   > const { id } = req.params;
   > const { avatar } = req.body;
   > const data = avatar.replace(/^data:image/\w+;base64,/, "");
   > const buf = Buffer.from(data, 'base64');
   >
   > ```
   > const login = await pool.query(
   >   "SELECT login FROM accounts WHERE id = $1", [id]
   > );
   >
   > fs.writeFile(`${userImgPath}/app_data/images/users/${login.rows[0].login}.png`,
   > ```
   >
   > buf, (err) => {
   > if (err) throw err;
   > console.log('The file has been saved!');
   > });   }   catch (err: any) {
   > console.error(err.message);   } });

Comment: yeah, i converted image data to string and passed to api post request with header and authorization it works !! .. previously it was giving me error because i have implemented base 64 in front end and my backend accepts only binary image

Answer (score 1):

Generally for uploading a photo on the nodejs they use [multer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer) package. You can see all details on its document. Also, you should set *multipart/form-data* on request's header. Here is the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47630163/axios-post-request-to-send-form-data)

I guess you can upload a photo on backend after you read those links