# Axios: data should be a string, Buffer or Uint8Array

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios, fs

I'm getting this error when trying to do a POST request using axios:

```
TypeError: data should be a string, Buffer or Uint8Array
```

Here is my code snippet:

```
var fs = require('fs'),
axios = require('axios');

var FormData = require('form-data');
var form = new FormData();
form.append('file', fs.createReadStream("qa_test_file_DOC.txlf"));
form.append('extractArchive', false);


let request_config = {
    headers: {
    'Authorization': `Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NXXXX.....`,
    ...form.getHeaders()
 }
}

let reqUrl = "https://XXXXX/XX/rest/v1/XXXXX";
try {
    axios.post(reqUrl, form, request_config)
        .then(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
        return callback(response);
     })
    .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
        return callback(error);
    });
} catch (ex) {
  console.log("exception   ", ex);
}
```

Tried using pipe, and most of possible solutions.  file is exist.  Not understanding what going wrong here.  anything in Readstream ?
Thanks for help.

Comment: Are you using TypeScript at all? If not, you really should - it's veritably impossible to write non-trivial application code without type annotations.

Comment: Are you certain your target endpoint supports `multipart/form-data` requests rather than putting files in the request body directly? (Because it isn't commonplace for RESTful web-services to accept data in `multipart/form-data` bodies).

Answer (score 30, accepted):

After spending much time and tried lots of possible things, I observed error that I am getting is.

```
TypeError: data should be a string, Buffer or Uint8Array
```

and in my formData I am appending one more variable with file is

```
form.append('extractArchive', false);
```

This is nothing but boolean and axios or formData is giving error for this.
I changed it to,

```
form.append('extractArchive', 'false');
```

That solved my issue. may it will help if someone running is such problem.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
axios.post(reqUrl, form, request_config)
```

You're passing a `FormData` object in the `form` argument. Axios (when used from within NodeJS) expects `string`, `Buffer`, or `Uint8Array`.

When using Axios inside a browser it just wraps `fetch` which allows `FormData` to be used directly), however when used inside NodeJS you'll need to serialize your own request body (and serializing to `multipart/form-data` can be painful, owing to `Boundary` fields, etc).

Assuming that you *actually* want to make a `multipart/form-data` request then:

- See this answer for how to send `multipart/form-data`: [Post form data with axios in Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41764184/post-form-data-with-axios-in-node-js)
- And this GitHub issue: https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/789

Comment: Hi,
Github issue: https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/789
It saying there is no native support.
Browser only: FormData, File, Blob // - Node only: Stream data: { firstName: 'Fred' },

I am trying it from Node.js service.

Comment: @PravinBhapkar What about it?

Answer (score -1):

update axios

for Node

```
npm i axios
```